# Dynamically add table row and binding to Server Side in Spring MVC

Tags: javascript, spring-mvc

I am designing an application with Spring MVC3. I have to create a JSP page which has a data table and user and can add rows in the JSP data table. I was considering the following two options:

1. To use JavaScript function to add a row on an "Insert Row" button
2. To submit the form on "Insert Row" button, go to Controller and return a model attribute with an extra row.

In JavaScript approach, I am able to add rows but these rows are not binding at server side. How can I achieve this using Controller approach?

Please note that I cannot use jQuery or any other JavaScript library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have achieved this using the `LazyList`. You need to have a lazy list object in your model which will hold the list of objects of the another model class which will represent data in each row. Following is the syntax to declare LazyList in your model class.

```
private List<OperationParameters> operationParameterses = LazyList
            .decorate(new ArrayList<OperationParameters>(),
                    FactoryUtils.instantiateFactory(OperationParameters.class));
```

And the OperationParameters is the simple pojo class whose one object will represent your 1 row.

Once you have this lazy list in your modelAttribute class then on the jsp you need to create control for each property in your OperationParameters pojo with help of simple html input tag. You can not use spring form taglib to bind those controls to your pojo. You need to give the name of each input tag as per following.

```
<input type='text' id='operationParameterses0.inputOutputParamName' name='operationParameterses[0].inputOutputParamName'/>
```

where in the name and id attribute the '0' represents the index of the list. Now when you submit the form you can get those inserted rows binded to the pojo in the LazyList object.

Hope this helps you.

Cheers.

Comment: but how i will bind those rows added by java script to this lazy list??

Comment: It will be managed by Spring automatically. You just need to specify the ID and Name in the format I have mentioned. Create the input tag with this ID and name and when you submit the form you will get every row in your list.

Comment: You need to maintain the counter of the number of rows added and on each new row added you need to increase the counter and put that counter in place of '0' in the id and name attribute in the tag.

Comment: may you suggest me ,how can i increse this counter by 1 while clicking on 'add Row' button???

Comment: You need to have a global variable in your javascript that will have the counter value. When user clicks on the add row button you need to add 1 in the counter and create the new row having the controls with the id and name as I suggested with this incremented counter value.

Comment: here num is my global variable

Comment: my add function looks like:var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var element1 = document.createElement("input");
    var id1="rowsList["+num+"].action";
    alert(id1);
    element1.type = "text";
    element1.id=id1;
    element1.name=id1;
    cell1.appendChild(element1)  but it is showing error in ID assigning...

Comment: japs,i have one more issue.when i am adding row using javascript and click on submit button...then my control go to controller and returun to view..but here it is not showing the added rows(added with javascript).....can you suggest how to deal with it?

Comment: Show me what exactly you are trying to do. Or post another question and provide me its link in following comment here.

Comment: i am adding rows to HTML table(clicking on add Button) using javascript in jsppage..while clicking on submit button,when control return back to view from controller,it is not showing the previously added row....

Comment: But you need to show me the code of View page and the controller from where you are showing the view page.

Comment: Hi Japs can you share your views and controllers via a google drive link.Please upload in the google drive,make a public sharing and sahre the link here,dont worry i will not share your code with any one

Comment: @NagappaLM There is no rocket science in this implementation. You can straightaway declare the LazyList in the databean and simply bind the values to it in jsp as described in the answer by me. Please post another question and provide its link here if you find any problem in this implementation. Also don't forget to upvote the answer if you found it useful. :)